# libinput documentation? mouse configuration

Tags: mouse

I'm trying to change the parameters of my mouse.  So far what works is using

```
xinput --list-props [ID]
```

and then:

```
xinput --set-prop [ID] [property] [value]
```

But I can find no general document explaining all the settings that can be changed.  Or perhaps something specific for my mouse (Logitech M310).  In particular the 'Coordinate Transform Matrix' seems useful:

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (138): 0.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.400000
```

All the "0.4" values are X axis, Y axis and acceleration sensitivities respectively.  But what are the other values for?  And there's a dozen other parameters which are available to change, but it would be nice to have some information about what they all do.  Any documents recommended?

Comment: Does this suffice: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/

Comment: `man libinput` should help

Comment: The doc has no specifics, but the man page is useful, thanks.